# Program causing NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Here's file named "Algorithm.java"

```
package leetcode;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Algorithms {
    public static int romanToInteger(String roman) {
        Map<String, Integer> romanValues = new HashMap<>();

        romanValues.put("I", 1);
        romanValues.put("V", 5);
        romanValues.put("X", 10);
        romanValues.put("L", 50);
        romanValues.put("C", 100);
        romanValues.put("D", 500);
        romanValues.put("M", 1000);
        int integer = romanValues.get(Character.toString(roman.charAt(roman.length() - 1)));
        int previousValue = integer, current;

        for (int i = roman.length() - 2; i >= 0; i--) {

            current = romanValues.get(Character.toString(roman.charAt(i)));

            if (current < previousValue) {
                integer -= current;
            } else {
                integer += current;
            }

            previousValue = current;
        }
        return integer;
    }
}
```

and here's "Main.java" from where I am calling the code

```
package leetcode;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Algorithms.romanToInteger("XII"));
    }
}
```

I am new to Java and I don't understand why this line is causing a NullPointerException.

`int integer = romanValues.get(roman.charAt(roman.length() - 1));`

But when I convert romanValues.get() argument to String like this

`int integer = romanValues.get(Character.toString(roman.charAt(roman.length() - 1)));`

it runs fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int integer = romanValues.get(roman.charAt(roman.length() - 1));`

Let's review the sequence of operations in the failing code:

1. `roman.charAt(roman.length() - 1)` - returns the last `char` of `roman` string
2. `romanValues.get` - according to `Map` javadoc [an `Object`is expected](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get-java.lang.Object-) in runtime -- here the specific type of the key is already erased -- therefore the `char` value is boxed into `Character`, however, as the map is defined with `String` key, the `get` returns `null` -- nothing is found for a `Character` key.
3. Assignment `int integer = null` causes un-boxing (an `Integer` has to be converted to primitive `int`) and this attempt causes `NullPointerException` because `null` is returned by `get`.

So in order for the mentioned code to work with `Character` key, you could also fix the type of keys in `romanValues` map and possibly use [`getOrDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) to provide default value for the missing keys:

```java
Map<Character, Integer> romanValues = new HashMap<>();

romanValues.put('I', 1);
romanValues.put('V', 5);
romanValues.put('X', 10);
romanValues.put('L', 50);
romanValues.put('C', 100);
romanValues.put('D', 500);
romanValues.put('M', 1000);

int integer = romanValues.getOrDefault(roman.charAt(roman.length() - 1), 0);
```

Comment: This makes sense. Can you explain the 3rd point further? I mean to ask if null is wrapped around by Integer object?

Answer (score 0):

Map.get : Map.get return returns null if the specified key is null and this mapdoes not permit null keys(optional))

String.charAt(roman.charAt) : return char

### Therefore

key of romanValues(Map<String, Integer>)  is String. It is difference between char and String.

for example

```
//false
System.out.println("A".equals('A'));
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Map.get return returns null if the specified key is null and this mapdoes not permit null keys(optional)"? Could you please explain it further?

Comment: It is written in javadoc. NullPointerException - if the specified key is null and this mapdoes not permit null keys(optional) Therefore if map doesn't have key, It return null.Try to execute this ex)  System.out.println(romanValues..get(Character.valueOf('A')));